# Microsoft Kaizala custom action import not working

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

Wehn we try to import the custom action to Kaizala portal, it throw "missing package.json" error,the package.json exist in the zip.

Answer (score 1):

1. Zip all the files into a single zip file
2. Make sure that the zip does not include another directory inside it but the files are 
    present at the root directory of the zip

For more help you may go through this link (Microsoft Docs) :- 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/actions/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

We find this error, mostly when we make mistake of zipping the folder, rather zipping only the folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows do not select Custom Action Source Folder to zip.
Go inside the Custom Kaizala Action folder you created and Select All then try zipping.

[Check Practice Tutorial: Creating a new Kaizala Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/actions/tutorial)

Step 9: Create the Kaizala Action package

- Zip all the files into a single zip file
- Make sure that the zip does not include another directory inside it – but the files are present at the root directory of the zip